# Android Studio: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE when compile(exclude did not work)

Tags: java, android, gradle, meta-inf

I added some libraries to my proyect to convert docs to PDFs.

When I compile it returns this error:

```
    :app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\ivan7\AndroidStudioProjects\Nsd2.0\app\libs\poi-3.9.jar
    File2: C:\Users\ivan7\AndroidStudioProjects\Nsd2.0\app\libs\poi-ooxml-3.9.jar


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.499 secs
```

With this gradle file :apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/itext-2.1.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/stax-api-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.9.jar')
}


android {



    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oneorzero.nsd20"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }




}
```

I've been reading some answers an I tried to exclude the META-INF/LICENSE but now i have this error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlSimpleList$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.SchemaRegularExpression$3) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.validator.ValidatingXMLInputStream$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil$2) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCodeGenerator$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaResourceManager$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XsbDumper$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.CharUtil$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.jam.JamUtils$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.RussianDollStrategy$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.util.Type$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"trouble processing \"javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class\":","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"when not building a core library.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"in your application\u0027s project, when using an IDE (such as","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Eclipse). If you are sure you\u0027re not intentionally defining a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what\u0027s","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"going on.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"It is also often of questionable legality.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"the \"--core-library\" option to suppress this error message.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you go ahead and use \"--core-library\" but are in fact","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"building an application, then be forewarned that your application","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"system. You will be to blame for this problem.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.445 secs
```

With this Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.itext.extension-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/itext-2.1.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/stax-api-1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar')
    compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.9.jar')
}


android {

    packagingOptions{

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oneorzero.nsd20"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }




}
```

Hope you could tell me an answer.

Comment: where did you put your pdf files?

Comment: @Rajesh.k which pdfs and why u need  to konw?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and solved it by putting that code in app gradle

```
android {
-------

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
}
}
```